# Is there any corpora for automatic text summarization?

Tags: nlp, text-mining, topic-modeling, summarization

I'd like to work on different task related to text summarization:

- topic/keyword extraction
- sentence extraction

What english corporus exist to help in this task?

Answer (score 2):

Have a look at TAC shared tasks: http://www.nist.gov/tac/2011/Summarization/

Edit: You can go back in time and see previous TAC/DUC summarization shared tasks. Also note for some of the data you require to sign some license agreements.

Answer (score 1):

The 20 newsgroups dataset is a popular one for topics. If you use python, you can access it using scikit learn.See here for more info: http://scikit-learn.org/stable/datasets/twenty_newsgroups.html